# How can I force a video played in a UIWebView to be full screen on an iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube-api, mpavcontroller

I'm playing a YouTube video using a UIWebView, like so:

```
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO;
[self.webView loadHTMLString:videoEmbedCode baseURL:nil];
```

I want to force the video to play in full screen without the user tapping the button at the bottom right. This works fine on an iPhone (tap the player to play and it automatically enters full screen), but doesn't work on an iPad (the normal inline player is shown).

I assumed that setting `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `NO` would do the trick, but apparently not.

**Is there a way to force HTML5 videos to play in full screen on an iPad?**

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to play a youtube video in fullscreen directly, then Use a webview of size fullScreen and then handle its rotation accordingly and change the player size of Rotation too. If you need more help then i can help you with the code too for how to change the player size on rotation too.

Comment: That's just a big inline player, not full screen. Full screen hides the status bar, activates different controls, has different animations, etc.

Comment: yeah, some months ago i faced the same problem and i have to use this big web-View to load videos as in ipad it was not possible to do so, But there are some free projects available on GitHub which provides very similar player to IOS native player and you can use that too.